# How to get the id of saved object by JPA?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I want to get the ID of the object saved to the database by JPA. Consider an object `person`, I save this object using

```java
personrepo.save(person)
```

How can I get the ID of this object?

Note: ID is the only unique column in this object.

Comment: save()-call returns the saved entity, so there you can get the id

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you work with Spring Data, method save returns persisted object with generated ID. So:

```java
person = personrepo.save(person);
var id = person.getId();
```

For more details, see [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html#save-S-).